# Delay in sending messages

Tags: stock-android

I'm Using G3 rom v8 by bountyman334 on LG e980. Message sending is taking a lot of time, delay in sending of about 5-10 minutes and sometimes fails. Tried to update Rom but nothing worked. need help.

Answer (score 1):

This is About your Network, Not android.

> Network Busy or other reasons...

Contact with `Network-Operator`,

they can help you.

Comment: Other people using Same rom are facing this problem.

Comment: try this Simcart on another phone and check the problem still exist or not and tell us ...